# Replace the file on disk while running the migration

Tags: 7, migrations

I am changing the migration code (not written by me) to not create new files on migration but to re-use (or rewrite) the existing files.

The migration code looks like the following:

Source part:

```
$url = url('filename.json', array('absolute' => TRUE));
$this->source = new MigrateSourceJSON(new MultiListJSON($url), 'name', $fields);
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFieldCollection(
  'field_product_documents',
  array('host_entity_type' => 'node')
);
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
  array(
    'name' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
 MigrateDestinationFile::getKeySchema()
);
```

Destination part:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('file', 'MigrateFileBlob');
$this->addFieldMapping('value', 'blob');
$this->addFieldMapping('destination_file', 'name');
$this->addFieldMapping('filename', 'name');
$this->addFieldMapping('destination_dir' ,'dest_dir')
  ->defaultValue('private://');
```

This migration is only responsible for creating of the file entities from the `blob` which comes from a third party service.
There is another migration that is executed after this migration and is responsible for associating the file ids of the files created by this migration.

Following the [documentation of the MigrateDestinationFile](https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106), the following code could be used to replace the file on the directory:

```
<?php
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_my_image:file_replace')
         ->defaultValue(FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
?>
```

But, during the file migration I am not associating it with any field. Hence, it could not be used. Or I am not sure of the exact way to use it.

My main concern is (let's say) if I have a file `ABC.pdf` on disk (might not be associated with any entity), the migration should not create a new `ABC_0.pdf`.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary fix I have implemented the following in the `prepareRow` function.

```
function prepareRow($row) {
  // Delete the file if already present.
  $file_path = drupal_realpath($row->dest_dir . '/' . $row->name);
  if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    unlink($file_path);
  }
}
```

However, I am still not sure about the way it is recommended in the Migrate module.